# How can I read a string without punctuation by scanf()?

Tags: c++, string, input, scanf

I wrote this code but it don't avoid punctuation.

```
   string str;
   char ch[100];
   while(scanf("%s[a-z | A-Z ]",ch)!=EOF) 
   {
        str=ch;
        cout<<str<<endl;
   }
```

When I give the following input:

```
 road.sign read:
 went home.
```

It prints the following output:

```
road.
sign
read:
went
home.
```

Is there any way to improve this code for printing word without punctuation?

Comment: Why use `scanf` when you have `cin`/`getline` in `c++`?

Comment: Is there any way to do this by cin that avoid punctuation while taking input? getline will store a whole line but i need a single word to store .

Comment: `The Regex in scanf goes between % and s like %[^\n]s`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution could be store the entire sentence and then remove punctation symbols with a regex replace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::string str;
    std::regex reg(R"([.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()])");

    while(scanf("%s", str)!=EOF)
    {

        // Remove punctation
        str = regex_replace(str, reg, "");

        std::cout<<str<<std::endl;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an example from a [GeeksforGeeks Tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string/) to remove a character from a `char` string in C++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

void removeChar(char *s, int c){ 

    int j, n = strlen(s); 
    for (int i=j=0; i<n; i++) 
       if (s[i] != c) 
          s[j++] = s[i]; 

    s[j] = '\0'; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
   char s[] = "geeksforgeeks"; 
   removeChar(s, 'g'); 
   cout << s; 
   return 0; 
}
```

---

You could use `removeChar()` two times; 1. with `removeChar(str, '.');` and 2. with `removeChar(str,':')` to remove the dots and colons from a string.

Furthermore, You could also use it a third time with `removeChar(str, ';');` to remove the semicolons.

Your code would then look like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

void removeChar(char *s, int c){ 

    int j, n = strlen(s); 
    for (int i=j=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       if (s[i] != c)
       {
          s[j++] = s[i]; 
       }
    }

    s[j] = '\0'; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
   char ch[100];
   while(scanf("%s[a-z | A-Z ]",ch)!=EOF) 
   {
         removeChar(ch, '.'); 
         removeChar(ch, ':');
         removeChar(ch, ';');
         cout << ch << endl;
   } 

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: GeeksForGeeks? Really? How shall I say. Some people think that this is not one of the best C++ sites. See for example "#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; ". The correct answer is given by commenter Sumit

Comment: @ArminMontigny The result is as the OP requested and everything works well. I admit that the stated way might be a little more easier and appropriate but the technique provided in this tutorial quite works. If anything is commonly deprecated of it, please mind it explicitly.